# Double domain in Wordpress URL string

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

So I have a blog that is hosted on AWS, it's is a Bitnami Wordpress blog.  I am ready to go live with it now. So I have done the following:

Connect to the the blog and went to the directory: 
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress
And executed this command: 
sudo ./bnconfig --machine_hostname techielass.com

I also went into my wp-config.php file and changed the WP_SITEURL and WP_URL parts.

I modified the host file on my computer so I could test the blog was acting as expected and unfortunately, the URLs I get are like this:

> http://techielass.comtechielass.com/2016/10/connecting-to-wordpress-bitnami-saas-instance-on-aws-with-filezilla/

Meaning nothing really works as expected.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong - any advice?

Comment: Check your database. It's likely a find/replace was performed incorrectly. You can find this out by looking under your wp_options table, and looking at the two records named "siteurl" and "home". If they have a value of `http://techielass.comtechielass.com`, then there's your problem.

Comment: Will see if I can connect to my database somehow, don't have a client via the AWS portal as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Most MySQL clients like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) will allow you to connect via SSH tunneling. So even if your MySQL installation doesn't accept remote connections, you can configure your MySQL connection to use your SSH credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified your .htaccess file is not redirecting in a strange way?

I don't think you should need to change your wp-config.php file although maybe Bitnami does something non-standard for WordPress.

Comment: Should I just change my DNS records to point to the blog then and not modify the wp_config file?